# how to provide data in specflow

Tags: specflow, gherkin

I have a scenario outline: section in specflow and i want to provide data in example: section
The problem is I have two parameters, one is in Given and another is in Then ie.

```
Given: I have a value <input1>
And: trigger 
Then: the result should be <input2>
```

and values for both input is not same so how should I put those values in table ?

```
|input1|input2|
|one   |one   |
|two   |two   |
|three |
|four  |
```

I tried searching on google but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work? I'm not sure I understand what the problem is

```
Scenario Outline:
    Given I have a value <input>
    And trigger 
    Then the result should be <expectedResult>

Examples:
    |input | expectedResult|
    |one   | 1             |
    |two   | 2             |
    |three | 3             |
    |four  | 4             |
```

Comment: because input1 is my input for a webservice and input2 is my response.if i will put both like that then how would my definition file detect which one is input and which one is output.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the issue. I have updated my answer. What about your solution does not work?